# Easier Way Than IrReceiver.decodedIRData.command to Check IR Remote Received Data

Tags: c++, arduino

I'm relatively new to Arduino and I was trying to create a simple sketch that turns an LED light on when I press the up arrow on the remote and turns the LED light off when I press the down arrow. Right now, this is what I have:

```
#include <IRremote.h>

int RECEIVER_PIN = 12;


void setup() {
  // put your setup code here, to run once:
  Serial.begin(9600);
  pinMode(LED_BUILTIN, OUTPUT);
  IrReceiver.begin(RECEIVER_PIN);
}

void loop() {
  // put your main code here, to run repeatedly:
  if(IrReceiver.decode()){    
    
    if(IrReceiver.decodedIRData.command == 0x46) {
      digitalWrite(LED_BUILTIN, HIGH);
    } else if(IrReceiver.decodedIRData.command == 0x15) {
      digitalWrite(LED_BUILTIN, LOW);
    }
    
    IrReceiver.resume();
  }

}
```

Is there a better way to do this or am I on the right track. All feedback is welcomed and appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I'm also new to Arduino and C, but if it was me I'd use "switch" instead of "if..then..else..if..etc" :

```
    #include <IRremote.h>

    int RECEIVER_PIN = 12;

    void setup() {
      // put your setup code here, to run once:
      Serial.begin(9600);
      pinMode(LED_BUILTIN, OUTPUT);
      IrReceiver.begin(RECEIVER_PIN);
    }

    void loop() {
      // put your main code here, to run repeatedly:
      if(IrReceiver.decode()){    
       switch(IrReceiver.decodedIRData.command){
           case 0x46: Serial.println("UP")                  ; digitalWrite(LED_BUILTIN, HIGH); break;
           case 0x15: Serial.println("DOWN")                ; digitalWrite(LED_BUILTIN, LOW) ; break;
           case 0x0:  Serial.println("Too Fast, Cmd Repeat"); break;
           default:   Serial.println("Ooops, wrong key!");    
        }
        IrReceiver.resume();
      }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this code, it works fine

```
#include <IRremote.h>

int receive_pin=12;
int led=8;

void setup(){
IrReceiver.begin(receive_pin);
pinMode(led,OUTPUT);
Serial.begin(9600);
}

void loop()
{
if(IrReceiver.decode())
{
Serial.println(IrReceiver.decodedIRData.command,HEX);
if(IrReceiver.decodedIRData.command==0x16){
  digitalWrite(led,HIGH);
}
if(IrReceiver.decodedIRData.command==0x19)
{
digitalWrite(led,LOW);
}
delay(1500);
IrReceiver.resume();
}
}
```

Comment: About 0x16 and 0x19 are the bottons from my IR remote, you can check yours using the Serial Monitor while you are pressing any botton then change it to your code.